# using svn and mercurial in eclipse for same project

Tags: eclipse, svn, mercurial

Is it possible to have in eclipse 2 "team providers" for same project. E.g. svn and mercurial?
So svn will be used to commit to central repository, and mercurial only to work on my PC. 
E.g. when I get updates from SVN, I commit to mercurial, then I work with mercurial. When everything is ready to go to central place, i commit in SVN. There is no need to integrate change history.

Yes, ideally it will be just mercurial, and most probably it will happened later. But for now I want to try  some dirty and fast solution if it exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you should have a look at HgSubversion. It's quite stable (I'm using it successfully for more than a year now). Combined with MercurialEclipse for the Hg integration with Mercurial.

Regarding purely your original question, the answer is: no, there is no way to add two team providers on a given project. That's one of the hard limit of the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: ok, I will probably try to move to Mercurial completely

Answer (score 2):

Use the third-party tool, [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion), to [achieve what you're after](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).

*Note: It may not be (easily) integrated with Eclipse though...*

Comment: I've tried hgsubversion and found that it works, but it can be flaky at times.  I'd recommend getting moved over to a purely Mercurial system as soon as possible if you're going down this route.

Answer (score 0):

I use Hg and SVN in the Same project . Since it is very risky to commit every single change to SVN (since it is production code) , we are using Hg for internal commits. Once everything is working fine , one person takes care of checking in into SVN .

Comment: Does this person work from eclipse (for both: SVN and Hg) or use some separate tools?